# Cannot pass a repository parameter to a specific controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

> I am using simple membership for account registration and I need to store extra data when the user registers.  I'm using Ninject for dependency injection and I already have a repository that gets a list of states to populate a dropdownlist.  I can pass this as a parameter to the constructor in my other controllers it works fine.  However, it returns null when I try to pass it to my account controller.  Obviously, there is some difference between this controller and my others but I can't figure out what it might be.  This is how I am passing the repository parameter to the constructor.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

private readonly IStateRepository sRepository;

public AccountController(IStateRepository sRepo)
{
    sRepository = sRepo;
}

public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {

        var stateQuery = sRepository.States.Select(m => new SelectListItem
        {

            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.StateID),
            Text = m.State1,
            Selected = m.StateID.Equals(0)
        });

        model.StateList = stateQuery.AsEnumerable();


        //more code to submit the registration


        return View(model);
    }
}


public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Apt #")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public string StateId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateList { get; set; }
}
```

Dropdownlist from Register view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, Model.StateList)
```

Repository interface

```
 public interface IStateRepository
{
    IQueryable<State> States { get; }
}
```

Repository

```
public class EFStateRepository : IStateRepository
{
    //private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
    private Entities context = new Entities();

    public IQueryable<State> States
    {
        get { return context.States; }

    }
}
```

Binding

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IStateRepository>().To<EFStateRepository>();
```

Has anyone else had this problem?  Edited to add - Help is also gratefully received from people who have not had this problem, but have suggestions. :-)

Comment: Are you only interested to hear from people who had this problem, or are you interested to get this problem solved? In that case, post more code, because your question is currently too vague.

Comment: Please show us your `IStateRepository` binding configuration and more of your controller (class definition and some action method where `sRepository` is null).

Comment: Steven - Of course I'm interested in hearing from anyone who can help me get this problem solved and also understanding why it occurred...  I will post more code in my original post.

Comment: mipe34 - Is there a reason you think it might be the binding?  I have used the repository for the exact same purpose (a "states" dropdownlist) in another controller and it works fine.

Comment: @MountainBiker - Of course, there is lot of things around binding. Personally I sometimes mismatch interface declaration `IRepository` with `Repository` or the binding could be conditional...etc. I think it is more relevant to your question to show us the binding configuration than model definition.

Comment: I have added the Interface, repository and binding to the original post.  Thanks again for taking the time to try and help.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see anything suspicious in your code. (Only one not related advice - do dispose your db context at the end of the request - e.g. make your repository disposable and declare binding `InRequestScope`

Comment: Mipe34 - I figured it out.  It was one of those embarrassing rookie mistakes that reminded me that I'm still very much an mvc novice. :-D  Thanks for the reminder to dispose the context, though.  I definitely need to do that.